# Selenium WebDriver's sendKeys only types new lines

Tags: java, iframe, selenium, tinymce

I'm trying to send some content to a cell inside a table.
The table is inside an iFrame, generated by TinyMCE.
For some reason, the only characters that are typed are "\n".

I have two methods: `switchToFrame()` and `switchToDefault()`, for switching between the iFrame and the window.

I have a method which types inside the `<body>` of the iFrame, which works just fine:

```
public void typeInBody(String content) {
    switchToFrame();

    WebElement body = driver.findElement(BODY_LOC);
    body.click();
    body.sendKeys(content);

    switchToDefault();
}
```

And here is the method to type inside a column:

```
public void typeInColumn(int index, String content) {
    switchToFrame();

    WebElement column = driver.findElement(COLS_LOC[index]);
    column.click();
    column.sendKeys(content);

    switchToDefault();
}
```

Finally, here is "the test" (is not a final test, is just for testing that the above methods work):

```
@Test(description = "see if tinyMCE methods work")
public void test() {
    String content = "Neque porro quisquam est \n" + 
                     "qui dolorem ipsum quia \n" + 
                     "dolor sit amet, \n" +
                     "consectetur, adipisci velit...";

    form = page.getForm();
    form.emptyFields(); // driver.findElement(BODY_LOC).clear();

    form.insertColumns(); // it's an option from tinyMC (just clicks the button)
    form.typeInColumn(0, content); // calls typeInColumn(0, content);

    form.clickSave(); // saves the form

    form = page.getForm(); // opens the form again
    // no assert for now
}
```

This is the TinyMCE after the test.

[image: TinyMCE with typeInColumn()]

and here is with `form.typeInBody(content);` which calls typeInBody(content).

[image: TinyMCE with typeInBody()]

Any idea why Selenium behave like this?

Comment: I doubt that the problem is Selenium itself. Are you sure that you are actually clicking and typing in the right element when you try to enter data in a column?

Comment: I have a function that highlights an element,  and when applied to that cell,  it highlights it. Also,  I've put a `Thread.sleep()` after `column.click() ` to see if the focus is there and it is. After that,  while on sleep(),  I even clicked myself on that cell to be sure. That's why I think it's from Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can say, it was from Selenium. Even though I put a `Thread.sleep()` and clicked myself inside the column, it still didn't recognized it inside the cell.

I put an `Action` object and made the changes (click and typing) to the cell with it and it worked.

The new code:

```
public void typeInColumn(int index, String content) {
    switchToFrame();

    WebElement column = driver.findElement(COLS_LOC[index]);

    Actions build = new Actions(driver);
    build.moveToElement(column).click().sendKeys(content).build().perform();

    switchToDefault();
}
```